# Javac: file not found: \*Java

Tags: java, windows, cmd

I am new to     `JMX` and following tutorials with in document. I added java bin     folder within path In command Prompt

```
c:\tutorial> javac -classpath ../lib/jmxri.jar:../lib/jmxtools.jar \*.java
```

But i am getting     `Javac: file not found: \*Java`    Error

I have below files with in Tutorial folder 
    `BaseAgent.java`
    `Simple.java`
    `SimpleDynamic.Java`
    `SimpleMBean.java`

Please Help

Comment: Why are you using `\*.java` instead of just `*.java`?

Comment: I remove `\*.java` and run only with `*.java` as per your Question and now i am getting different error and now i am getting `BaseAgent.java:30: error: package com.sun.jdmk.comm does not exists import com.sun.jdmk.com,htmlAdaptorserver:`

Comment: Then that's a different problem - you should delete this question, and research that error.

Comment: agreed..will do